# Using NSURLIsExcludedFromBackupKey to Disable Backups of a Folder in Documents

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, backup

My app, as of current, contains crucial files inside the Documents folder that go through the backup process so that they can be restored at a later date. These files are created by the users. However, there is also a folder inside the Documents directory, named `/Templates`, that I need to be excluded from backup. This consists of files that are downloaded with the app and are used to help create new files from a foundation: a template.

Therefore, my question is this: Is there any way to exclude a single folder within the Documents directory? I would also prefer to keep it in the Documents directory, if possible. Here is the message that I received from the iTunes Connect Resolution Centre.

> We found that your app does not follow the iOS Data Storage
> Guidelines, which is required per the App Store Review Guidelines.
>
> In particular, we found that on launch and/or content download, your
> app stores 102.71MB. To check how much data your app is storing:
>
> - Install and launch your app
> - Go to Settings > iCloud > Storage & Backup > Manage Storage
> - If necessary, tap "Show all apps"
> - Check your app's storage
>
> The iOS Data Storage Guidelines indicate that only content that the
> user creates using your app, e.g., documents, new files, edits, etc.,
> should be backed up by iCloud.
>
> Temporary files used by your app should only be stored in the /tmp
> directory; please remember to delete the files stored in this location
> when the user exits the app.
>
> Data that can be recreated but must persist for proper functioning of
> your app - or because customers expect it to be available for offline
> use - should be marked with the "do not back up" attribute. For NSURL
> objects, add the NSURLIsExcludedFromBackupKey attribute to prevent the
> corresponding file from being backed up. For CFURLRef objects, use the
> corresponding kCFURLIsExcludedFromBackupKey attribute.
>
> For more information, please see Technical Q&A 1719: How do I prevent
> files from being backed up to iCloud and iTunes?.
>
> It is necessary to revise your app to meet the requirements of the iOS
> Data Storage Guidelines.  If you have difficulty reproducing a
> reported issue, please try testing the workflow described in Technical
> Q&A QA1764: How to reproduce bugs reported against App Store
> submissions.
>
> If you have code-level questions after utilizing the above resource,
> you may wish to consult with Apple Developer Technical Support. When
> the DTS engineer follows up with you, please be ready to provide:
>
> - complete details of your rejection issue(s)
> - screenshots
> - steps to reproduce the issue(s)
> - symbolicated crash logs - if your issue results in a crash log

Answer (score 0):

```
- (BOOL)addSkipBackupAttributeToItemAtURL:(NSURL *)URL
{
    if (URL) {
        assert([[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:[URL path]]);

        NSError *error = nil;
        BOOL success = [URL setResourceValue: [NSNumber numberWithBool: YES]
                                      forKey: NSURLIsExcludedFromBackupKey error: &error];
        if(!success){
            NSLog(@"Error excluding %@ from backup %@", [URL lastPathComponent], error);
        }
        return success;
    }
    else
    {
        return YES;
    }
}
```

You can pass the url of the folder and this should work. This is how we disable backup for the entire documents folder.

Comment: Yes, and that is all well and done, but I wish to disable the backup of a folder within the documents folder.